# Sorting an array in PHP when the second and third value are known

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, object

I want to sort an array which will always contain three objects.

The script knows the name values of the objects that should be returned second and third.

How can I sort this array so that the order is correct?

```
$categories = Array ( 

[48] => stdClass Object ( 
    [term_id] => 48 
    [name] => Hello 
    [term_group] => 0 
    [term_taxonomy_id] => 57 
    [taxonomy] => resume_category 
    [description] => 
    [parent] => 0 
    [count] => 572 
    [object_id] => 18397 
    [filter] => raw 

) 

[64] => stdClass Object ( 

    [term_id] => 64 
    [name] => World 
    [term_group] => 0 
    [term_taxonomy_id] => 75 
    [taxonomy] => resume_category 
    [description] => 
    [parent] => 0 
    [count] => 22 
    [object_id] => 18397 
    [filter] => raw

)

[5] => stdClass Object ( 
    [term_id] => 5 
    [name] => Test 
    [term_group] => 0 
    [term_taxonomy_id] => 75 
    [taxonomy] => resume_category 
    [description] => 
    [parent] => 0 
    [count] => 22 
    [object_id] => 5 
    [filter] => raw  

)
```

I want Hello as the second value and World as the last value but the values and order of the array are dynamic and will vary:

```
   foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
    echo $category->name;
    echo ', ';
   }
```

Should return: test, hello, world

Comment: Custome sorting task? `usort()`

Comment: Can you provide a sample array and explain your desired sorting algorithm? Ie: alphabetical on key 2.

Comment: In the first line, "hello" and "world" are lower case. In the end, the first letter is capitalized. Case matters a great deal with sorting. Are you planning to ucwords the values unless the value is "test"?

Comment: I see all values are lowercase now. The reason you cannot sort the array is because $categories has only one value: "test". No matter how you sort it, you will only get "test". The problem is that you are using the same key for every value in the declaration. You assign "hello" to "name", then change "name" to "world", and then change "name" to "test".

Comment: As @kainaw mentioned it's not a valid PHP array so it's unclear what you want to achieve

Comment: I am getting all categories from a Wordpress function but will update the array ;)

Comment: `foreach ( $categories as $category ) : 
echo $category->name;
endif;` From your example category should be an array, and endif should be endforeach

Comment: Are you trying to move the object with name = 'hello' to position 2 and object with name = 'world' to position 3? Your question is very unclear!

Answer (score 0):

In fact you don't need sorting an array but you want to recreate it.

You should use the following function:

```
function changeArrayOrder($categories) {
    $categories = array_values($categories);
    return array (
        $categories[2],
        $categories[0],
        $categories[1],
    );
}
```

and run it using:

```
$categories = changeArrayOrder($categories);
```

Now if you run your loop you will get result:

```
test, hello, world,
```